# Get image from marketplace WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I'd like to do a **best of application** list. It is just a list with a title and an image.
I saw the `MarketplaceDetailTask();` who take the `marketPlaceId` `(marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier)`.

My question is, is there a way, knowing this Id, to get the image url of the corresponding app ?

I've done some research but nothing about an API or something to return this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in API in Windows Phone to retrieve this kind of information. However, you can try querying directly the service used by the Zune client. This service isn't publicly documented, but there's a few blog posts explaining how to use it. For instance:

http://brandonwatson.sys-con.com/node/1767886

Comment: Great, thanks to you I've found a documentation for the Zune Catalog Service (http://zunedata.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=API%20Documentation). An exemple: http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/image/f6774d57-815d-476e-a27e-44f6048d2f5e?width=150&height=150